# Get top 5 categories have a particular tag from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I was trying to get the top five categories form Wordpress in the order of post count ,which have a tag with the given tag id using the below code.but always it return empty array.but there is data exist,what is wrong with this?

```
            $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'number'=>5,
                'orderby'=>'count',
                'order' =>'DESC',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'tag',
                        'value'   => 10,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ) );
```

Comment: Where is this code getting called? e.g. is it in a template, or if its in functions.php what is calling it?

Comment: I am calling it on my custom plugin

Comment: And when would it get called? e.g. a single page, archive page, etc?

Comment: Also, what is your version of wordpress? `get_terms` changed in WP4.5

Comment: this is called in single post and my wordpress version is 4.8.2